# How to create a releationship linking to PK column Plus another

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to create a relationship between two models where the child links to the PK id plus another Id column in the parent

```
Public Class AClass
{
    public int AClassId {get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }       

    public ICollection<BClass> LinkedUsers { get; set; }

    public int SubUserId { get; set;}
    public User SubUser{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<BClass> LinkedSubUsers { get; set; }
}

Public Class BClass
{
    public int BClassId {get; set; }

    public int AClassId {get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public AClass AClass { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Rules> Rules { get; set; }
}
```

So BClass can only Exist if AClass has a set UserId or a SubUserId linked to it. Multiple AClass can have multiple instances of BClass for the same User

```
public Aclass a = new Aclass();
a.AClassId = 1;
a.UserId = 1;
a.SubUserId = 2;

//Ok
BClass b1 = new BClass();
b1.AClassId = 1;
b1.UserId = 1;

//Ok
BClass b2 = new BClass();
b2.AClassId = 1;
b2.UserId = 1;

//OK
BClass b3 = new BClass();
b3.AClassId = 1;
b3.UserId = 2;

//Not OK No AClass 1 with UserId 3
BClass b1 = new BClass();
b1.AClassId = 1;
b1.UserId = 3;
```

I'm creating the relationship using:

System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration

```
HasRequired(c => c.AClass).WithMany(i => i.LinkedUsers).HasForeignKey(t => new { t.AClassId, t.UserId } );
```

but I get the error:

"The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical."

I hope this is possible but can't work out how to create the correct mapping using EF.

Comment: Your code seems incompete. Where is the `foreign-keys` in `BClass` for `public ICollection<BClass> LinkedSubUsers { get; set; }`?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm going about this the correct way, I was thinking that B's UserId could be either UserId or SubUserId of A and I would need two relationships one for UserId and one for SubUserId. But that would require them to be optional if its at all possible.